# Avoiding calls to theme-compat

Tags: comments

I have developed my own theme as a variant of Twenty Eleven.

I am trying to avoid having `aria-required` being printed by the comments template. For ease of maintenance I'd rather override the comment template in my own theme than change the one that is currently being called.

How do I go about overriding the comment template in my own theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to remove the `aria-required` attribute. It is a form attribute in draft at W3 that deals with accessibility for working with applications and handicapped users.

Anyway, you can remove it by filtering the `comment_form_default_fields` and `comment_form_field_comment`. The example below can be used as a plugin or in your theme's `functions.php` file and will remove the `aria-required` attribute.

```
/* Attach the custom_comment_form_fields() function to the comment_form_default_fields hook. */
add_filter( 'comment_form_default_fields',  'custom_comment_form_fields' );

/* Attach the custom_comment_form_field_comment() function to the comment_form_field_comment hook. */
add_filter( 'comment_form_field_comment',   'custom_comment_form_field_comment' );

/** 
 * Remove the aria-reuqired from name and email comment fields. 
 */
function custom_comment_form_fields() {

    /* Get current commenter. */
    $commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();

    /* Check if name and email fields are required. */
    $req = get_option( 'require_name_email' );

    /* Remove the aria-required attribute. */
    $fields =  array(
        'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . __( 'Name' ) . '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
                    '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30" /></p>',

        'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'Email' ) . '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
                    '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30" /></p>',

        'url'    => '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( 'Website' ) . '</label>' .
                    '<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30" /></p>'

    );
    return $fields;

}

/** 
 * Remove the aria-reuqired from comment textarea field. 
 */
function custom_comment_form_field_comment() {
    /* Comment text area. */
    $textarea = '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">' . _x( 'Comment', 'noun' ) . '</label><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8"></textarea></p>';

    return $textarea;
}
```

Comment: The reason is that I want my sites to pass validation, although I'm really tempted these days not to as it's basically too much effort with all these plugins and javascript widgets flying around.